# Can GDB help to find out when a memory address is freed?

Tags: c, gdb

Can GDB track when a memory address is freed? Putting a `watch` on the address doesn't help, since it does not break when memory at address is freed, but only when it is touched.

I think by using `free()`, only the pointer to the memory is freed, but the contents can still exist, until it is used by another memory allocation function.

```
(gdb) p (char *)0xee20229c
$2 = 0xee20229c "XYZ"
(gdb) watch *(char *)0xee20229c
Hardware watchpoint 3: *(char *) 3995083420
(gdb) c
Continuing.
...
...
Hardware watchpoint 3: *(char *) 3995083420

Old value = 88 'X'    // Changes only when the contents are overwritten,
New value = 0 '\0'    // but not when the memory location '0xee20229c' is freed.
```

Comment: you can break on `free()` but it smells like you want valgrind along with GDB.

Comment: You can set a conditional breakpoint with `break ... if cond`.  So you could set a breakpoint in `free(void *p)` with the condition `if p == 0xee20229c`.

Comment: @indiv but for `condition` I would need to specify the exact argument passed to `free()`, which might not be the same name across functions. And I cannot find the place where this memory is freed to provide the exact argument name for the `condition`.

Answer (score 4):

> Can GDB track when a memory address is freed?

In general, no. However, if you know something about the `malloc` and `free` being used, then yes.

> Putting a watch on the address doesn't help, since it does not break when memory at address is freed, but only when it is touched.

That is correct.

> I think by using free(), only the pointer to the memory is freed,

A pointer can't be freed. A block of memory that the pointer points to is freed.

> but the contents can still exist, until it is used by another memory allocation function.

Correct.

So, if you want to know when `0xee20229c` is being freed, and you know nothing about your malloc implementation, then the only way to solve this is with conditional breakpoint on `free`.

> but for condition I would need to specify the exact argument passed to free(), which might not be the same name across functions.

I am not sure what you mean. The condition you want is: the address being free'd is `0xee20229c`

Setting this condition may require that you have debug info available for your `libc`, or that you specify it via registers (you'll need to know the ABI for your platform).

What if you *do* know something about `malloc`?

Many malloc implementations keep "housekeeping" info just before the heap block. If your implementation does, then setting a watchpoint on `address-of-interest - 4` or `- 8` may get you desired result.

Comment: I can set a breakpoint on `__GI___libc_free`, but on defining the condition what should I say - `cond bnum (0xee20229c)` ? I know about the memory implementation of malloc, but looking at the memory block they dont seem to match up. Also, if a block of memory pointed to by pointer is freed and the content of that memory location is not freed, then what does free() really do?

Answer (score 0):

The Russian's answer is not incorrect, but you can do some things to determine whether the memory is freed in gdb, if you are willing to run the program multiple times.

Since you are using gdb, you can simply free the memory in question a second time. If the program has a segmentation error on the second free, you tried to free memory that was already freed.

In an alternate method, you can also set the memory pointer to NULL when it is freed. Then you only need to check for the NULL pointer. While this might seem cleaner, you will be erasing some info that could be useful in your hunt for memory issues.

Valgrind and "g++ -g -fsanitize=address yourProgram.cpp -o yourProgram -lasan" will also give some info which can be used to narrow the search. They are not infallible, though.